# "Edit Bookmark" option missing from bookmark context menu in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

What happened to the "edit bookmark" option in Chrome's bookmark manager context menu?

I'm not sure when this option disappeared, but I believe you used to be able to edit the URL and other bookmark manager things from the top-level bookmark context menu.

I no longer see a URL field for the bookmark, nor the bookmark manager shortcut in the top-level context menu.

I assume this was disabled in some Chromium release.
Is there a config option or extension that restores this feature?

[image: Chrome bookmark manager context window]

Comment: same problem, I used this a lot. Just Disable chrome://flags/#power-bookmarks-side-panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is still a way to activate it. You can go to this address, `chrome://flags/#power-bookmarks-side-panel` and disable it. After that, and relaunching Chrome, you should get the "more" option when you click on the star that permits you to change the URL.

Comment: This was removed a few days ago. All of the code for the More button, as well as the related flag, has been deleted from Chromium's source code: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/4918463
There is a ticket complaining about this change here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1487656
One of the Chrome devs there said, quote, "This change was intentional, we simplified the dialogue...".

Comment: That is a very sad UX story that it was intentional. And thank you for linking to it.

Comment: I don't see `#power-bookmarks-side-panel` in Brave fwiw. But I do see `brave://flags/#power-bookmark-backend` which is disabled by default, however after enabling and relaunch I do not see the previous functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A 3-click workaround

1. On your current image, you can see the `Folder "Bookmarks bar"` **dropdown**, click on it
2. Choose on the Bottom `Choose another folder...`
3. This will allow for editing the URL too

This way you don't need to change anything in the flags, and it just takes 3 more clicks, still a user experience regression but it does work.

[image: edit bookmark initial dialog]

[image: choose folder dialog, with URL edit]

Comment: Thank you! I like this answer more than a flag. I edited it to add some screenshots and clarified that it allows one to edit the URL too.